# Ruby TCP Client Server

Tags: ruby, tcp

I am working on a project where I have implemented a TCP client server for a device communication. In order to send a command from the server to the client, I am building a command that the device understands and sending to it but the response is not what should be returned

```
 while 1
   Thread.start(@otd.accept) do |client| 
   loop do

      command_to_send ="<R-2,3,4>"
      client.puts command_to_send
      puts "Command #{command_to_send}sent"
      #sleep 2
      response = **client.gets** # here it halts and never puts the the next statement.
      puts "Reponse #{response}"

   end # end of nested loop     
   client.close 
   end #END OF THREAD.
 end #end of while loop
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: You need to show us both endpoint's code.

Comment: Martin Konecny the other end point is basically a device that communicates over tcp.

Comment: guys I am really stuck in here.  client.gets stucks forever. are there any alternatives to client.puts and client.gets ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use gets as it expects '\n' to be a delimiter of the message.
Instead use: recv here is a method that could help you:

```
def read(timeout = 2, buffer = 1024)
    message = ''
    begin
      Timeout::timeout(timeout) do 
        buffer = client.recv(buffer)
        message += buffer
      end
    rescue Timeout::Error
      puts "Received nothing from client: #{client.__id__}"
      message = ''
    rescue Exception => e
      raise "Client failed to read for reason - #{e.message}"
    end
  message
end
```

You do not have to use sleep anymore as recv like gets is blocking. But the timeout makes sure you are not stuck waiting for a response not existing.